# set a defined user agent to an iFrame

Tags: css, html, iframe, user-agent

Is it possible to set a defined user agent to an iFrame? If yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible since the browsers have fixed user agent strings that they send with all request regardless of whether its from an iframe or not. And this is not something modifiable via JS.

You can however, have a script on your server which spoofs the user agent string (via curl for example) and then have your iframe call *that* script which in turn fetches the page you want called with a different user agent string and returns the output back to your iframe. For example: `http://yourserver.com/yourproxy?url=<http://url-to-fetch/page>&ua=<user-agent-string-to-use>`

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in a normal browser.  The useragent that will be given to a server cannot be set via javascript.  Some browsers allow you to mess with the useragent, but the only ones I've seen that allow that do it for all browser requests, not just for one particular iframe request.

Perhaps if you share the problem you're really trying to solve, we'd be more likely to be able to help.

Comment: @jfriend000 : I am trying to simulate an iphone browser in an iframe and think of passing a user agent to it !! is something wrong with my approach ?

Comment: @Aditi There's actually browser plugins/add-ons for both FireFox and Chrome that can spoof user agents if you wish to test website functionality.